# My Preview Screen is not loading mobile device layout

Tags: android-layout

I am using Android Studio 2.2.3. When I am Looking for Preview it's not showing properly.

I am getting the preview screen like image 1. But I want the preview screen like image 2.

[image: previews]

Answer (score 0):

This new layout editor is available in Android Studio 2.2 and higher to be used with constraint layouts but if you still want to use old layout editor thn you will have to downgrade your android studio.